# How can I change the plugin update server for specific plugins?

Tags: plugins

There are specific plugins that I want to use my own repo for for updating my sites. How can I identify the plugin to target and what server they should be looking at?

Comment: since this question was asked, WP 5.8 added an official method of doing this via filters and the plugins header

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with the filter `plugins_api` :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_api/

try this code :

```
add_filter("plugins_api", function ($plugins_api, $action, $args) {

    if ("plugin_information" !== $action) {
        return $plugins_api;
    }


    $pluginSlug = $args->slug;


    if (... update available ...) {

        $plugins_api = new \stdClass();
        $plugins_api->name = $pluginSlug;
        $plugins_api->version = "5"; // new version
        $plugins_api->download_link = "https://server/directory/newVersion.zip";

        $plugins_api->slug = $pluginSlug;
        $plugins_api->sections = []; // sections of "view details" of update page when update is available

    }

    return $plugins_api;

}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Is specifying a version necessary and the "slug" is that the plugin's handle that needs to be updated? And do you have an example of specifying if the update is available?

Comment: Maybe I should specify - I'm trying to change the location of the update for an already existing plugin. I think the code and below's answer are for my own plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this solution, which is a bit more work to set up, but allows you to get updates from your own GitHub or private repository.  I use it for my own private plugin that contains my personal settings for all web sites I develop.

https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker#github-integration

Comment: Is there a way to use this outside of a plugin or theme's folder? I tried this in `functions.php` but it crashes `require '../../plugins/plugin-update-checker/plugin-update-checker.php';`

Comment: You have to adjust that require for the location of the functions.php. The process is built for a theme/plugin to look for updates in a non-WP repository; perhaps your own Github repository, or a spot on your domain. And the zip has to contain a folder that is the same name as the theme/plugin, then the plugin/theme files are in that subfolder. Carefully read/follow the instructions; it can be a bit tricky.